# How to ignore escaped character in regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex to match all words of a text starting with '+'.

```
Pattern.compile("\\+[\\w-]+");
```

This works well and matches `"+Foo or +Bar"` to `"+Foo"` and `"+Bar"`.

How can I extend the regex to ignore words starting with an escaped '+'-char?

`"+Foo or +Bar but no \\+Hello"` should match to `"+Foo"` and `"+Bar"` **but not to `"+Hello"`**.

(It should work for JDK1.7.)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!\\(\\{2})*)\+[\w-]+
```

In general, `(?<!Y)X` matches an `X` that is not preceded by a `Y`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use *negative look-behind*:

```
Pattern.compile("(?<!\\\\)\\+[\\w-]+");
```

Answer (score 3):

Java supports finite-length look-behind, so this should work:

```
"(?<!\\\\)\\+[\\w-]+"
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html